# Do i need my Root note, 3rd or 5ft note to be at down beat to be in Chord?

Tags: theory, chords, chord-theory

Do i need my Root note, 3rd or 5ft note to be at down beat to be  in Chord ?

Comment: Only if you want all your music to sound the same (and not very interesting either). Putting all the chord changes exactly on the down beats is a common beginner's mistake. There is no "rule" that says you can't put them anywhere you like.

Answer (score 2):

If you play the whole chord (Root, 3rd and 5th) on the down beat, it will clearly give the chord to the listener. So, if this is what you aim for, do it. *But*, if you play all your chords like this, the song might get boring away after a while, and that is why many musicians prefer to not give away all the notes at the down beat. You can play some chord notes on the down beat and some on the up beat or some on the down beat and some on the next beat (really depends on your rhythm).

Try out a few ways and see what you like best!

Answer (score 0):

No.  An arpeggio counts as a chord. And chords, broken or otherwise, don't have to come on a strong beat.